# How to export data from layout to file

Tags: android, pdf, itext, cloud

I am working on an android app project for work, in Android Studio, which contain texts and switch buttons. I would like to save all this data in file (PDF,excel, etc.), and then upload it to cloud.

How can I store all the data into file?

Do I have to use any Database?

I tried to use itext, and created a PDF containing only text.

Comment: Show us what you've tried with iText. How did you try to *add data*. In which way is the data different from text? Do you mean you don't know how to add *associated filed* (`/AF`)? Which version of iText are you using? Associated files are fairly recently added to the PDF specification; versions of iText older than the introduction of the `/AF` key don't support the feature (for obvious reasons). Or are you saying you can't render buttons? If so, please explain *how* you want to render the buttons using PDF specification language. Are you talking about AcroForm fields?

Comment: "How can I store all the data into file?" -- file I/O is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) and any good book on Android app development. Depending on the file format, you may need to combine it with libraries that know how to write files in that format. "Do I have to use any Database?" -- a database is a type of file. You are welcome to write your data to a database, or not, as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export data to a pdf file, using iText (as your tag indicates) there are various options.

- You can use the core API, which allows you to insert tables, lists and text. For more information you can  consult
  http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples
- You can export to HTML, and then use pdfHTML (newest iText add-on) to convert the given HTML to pdf. For more information (+examples) consult
  http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfhtml

Comment: Downvoting, because the OP is developing on Android, and iText 7 is not available for Android. There is however iTextG, which is the GAE/Android port of iText 5.

Comment: Strictly speaking, depending on the workflow my argument is still valid. If the OP pushes the data to a server (in JSON format for example) and sets up a process on the server to turn the incoming JSON into a pdf (by using a combination of JSON library + iText) the OP will get the exact functionality they're looking for.